# Google Chrome HttpPost issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser, http-post

I'm relatively new to ASP.net mvc, and am experiencing a very strange browser error. The problem is that it's on the customer's pc (which I have yet to get access to).

There seems to be an intermittent problem posting data from his computer, at the moment he has only tried chrome (and I have requested he try different browsers). I haven't been able to replicate the issue and have tried on two computers, three browsers and three different operating systems (windows 7, windows 8 (via mac parallels) and Osx Mavericks) .

I'll post the model and relevant controller code (hopefully it's not too sloppy coding)

I've clarified the following:
- we are both using the same version of chrome
- we both use the same ISP
- He has AVG running
-the site is hosted on Azure
- there is plenty of database and file memory allocated (only 10% being used)
- very little in my code has varied from online examples and again, it all works for me

So my question is really, where else do I look to find the errors:
- is there something in the code that I should consider adding or changing 
- could it be a cookie issue on his version of chrome?
- is there a firewall issue somewhere?

model

```
public class KitchenItem:Post
{


    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }


    //Optional Project Variables
    public bool Project { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime? projectStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? projectEnd { get; set; }

}
}
```

inherited model:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  string Title
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Short Description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText )]
    public  string ShortDescription
    { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed")]
    public string Description
    { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Meta Keywords")]
    [DefaultValue (" ")]
    public  string Meta
    { get; set; }



    public  string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }

    public  bool Published
    { get; set; }

    public  DateTime? PostedOn
    { get; set; }

    public  DateTime? Modified
    { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }


    public Category Category
    { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile { get; set; }
    public string mainImagePath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags
    { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateProjectViewModel
{
    public KitchenItem  KitchenItem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Upload Image")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] ImagesFiles { get; set; }


    public Image[] Images { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int[] imageDeletes { get; set; }
}
```

Create Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateProjectViewModel viewModel)
    {
        KitchenItem model = new KitchenItem();
        model = viewModel.KitchenItem;
        try
        {
            /* 
             *Create ID from total Images to allow for specific folders to be created when file saved, iteration (totalImages) 
             *Calls for loop for each element of array to ensure that specific titles and tags are associated to correct image
             * Add image to model collection to be saved to db                 
             */

            List<Image> imgCollection = new List<Image>();
            int totalKitchenItems = unitofWork.KitchenItemRepository.dbSet.Count() + 1;



            //update model images
            model.Images = handleEditImage(viewModel.ImagesFiles, viewModel.Images, imgCollection, model.Id);


            //Log date posted
            model.PostedOn = DateTime.Now;


            Category cat = new Category();

            model.Category = unitofWork.CategoryRepository.GetByID(viewModel.CategoryID);



            //create post
            unitofWork.KitchenItemRepository.Insert(model);
            unitofWork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                        validationError.PropertyName,
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
                foreach (var eve in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }


            PopulateCategoriesDropDownList(0);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
```

Handle Image & Add Image Functions:

```
 public ICollection<Image> handleEditImage(HttpPostedFileBase[] imageFiles, Image[] images, ICollection<Image> modelImages, int modelID)
    {           
        /* 
                *Create ID from total Images to allow for specific folders to be created when file saved, iteration (totalImages) 
                *Calls for loop for each element of array to ensure that specific titles and tags are associated to correct image
                * Add image to model collection to be saved to db                 
                */

        List<Image> imgCollection = new List<Image>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Image uploadImage = new Image();

            //check to make sure there is an image
            if (imageFiles[i] != null)
            {
                //handle httppostedfilebase conversion to image file and add Url to image model
                uploadImage = AddImage(imageFiles[i], images[i], modelID);
                //Add img to be updated to model
                imgCollection.Add(uploadImage);
            }

        }
        if (modelImages != null)
        {

            //check for deleted images
            foreach (var img in modelImages)
            {
                //loop through image array to determine whether image is currently assigned to model
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {

                    if (images[i].ImageUrl != null)
                    {
                        //replace string element modified before passed to view
                        images[i].ImageUrl = images[i].ImageUrl.Replace("../../", "~/");
                    }
                    if (img.ImageUrl == images[i].ImageUrl)
                    {

                        imgCollection.Add(img);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        return imgCollection;
    }

  public Image AddImage(HttpPostedFileBase imageToSave, Image modelImage, int Id)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img = modelImage;
        img.ImageUrl = SaveUploadedFile(imageToSave, Id);
        unitofWork.ImagesRepository.Insert(img);
        return img;
    }
```

Comment: It probably more has something to do with the client code, as it could be due to a malformed rendering of HTML, a JavaScript error, a plugin the user has installed that messes with the post...  it could be a multitude of issues, so it would help if you could elaborate on what type of symptoms the user is experiencing.

Comment: Hi Brian, he has described two different issues. The main issue is that when he creates an item it will appear to post, and then, having looking at the database to clarify, it does not post properly. The other issue he has described is when looked through the pagedlists they occasionally crash. I the site is built using a template from ThemeForest, I did put the scripts into Bundles and have had to remove some of the scripts and put direct links in the layout for them to work, this has been the minified files from what i can tell